# C - pointer passed to function does not retain assigned string

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I wrote my first lines of C a couple of days ago, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to create a function that reads from stdin and concatenates it in a single string. I have a solution that works, but it relies on the caller free()ing memory allocated within the function, which I don't really like from a design perspective.

***working code***

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_input(void)
{
  char *str = malloc(10 * sizeof(*str)); // I know, sizeof char = 1, still learning so I use it for practice/clarity
  // [...] malloc error check
  char buffer[BUFSIZ];
  int buffer_size = BUFSIZ - 1;

  while(fgets(buffer, buffer_size, stdin))
  {
    str = realloc(str, strlen(str) + strlen(buffer) +1);
    // [...] malloc error check
    strcat(str, buffer);
  }

  return str;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *str_input = get_input();
  printf("%s\n", str_input);
  free(str_input);

  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ echo "test" | bin/main
> test
> ```

I would much prefer if it was the caller's responsibility to also allocate memory before passing a pointer.

***troublesome code***

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_input(char *str)
{
  char buffer[BUFSIZ];
  int buffer_size = BUFSIZ - 1;

  while(fgets(buffer, buffer_size, stdin))
  {
    str = realloc(str, strlen(str) + strlen(buffer) +1);
    // [...] malloc error check
    strcat(str, buffer);
  }

  // printf("%s\n", str); <-- this prints normally when uncommented
}

int main(void)
{
  char *str_input = malloc(10 * sizeof(*str_input));
  get_input(str_input);
  printf("%s\n", str_input);
  free(str_input);

  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ echo "test" | bin/main
> ```

Oddly, if I try and print the value of `str` just before exiting the function, it works. Also, if I move the whole code within the function to main, it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Remember that C only pass arguments *by value*, meaning the value of the arguments in the call are copied into the formal argument variables in the function. So whatever you pass as argument to the `get_input` function is local inside the `get_input` function only, once the function returns the lifetime of the argument variables ends as they go out of scope, meaning all changes to them are lost. I suggest you do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C* for a solution. Or return the pointer.

Comment: Also, you malloc() the string, redundantly realloc() it, the pass it to strcat() before putting anything in that memory. Strcat only concatenates to existing strings, and you have no reason to think your malloc'd area contains a valid string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought by passing a pointer to allocated memory I was doing just that. Even if the pointer gets copied, is the copy not pointing to the same address? Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll be reading up on that.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I was surprised that this worked without first using strcpy(), but since it did I thought I'd save myself a step. I'll add a call to strcpy() before the while loop.

Comment: If the random bytes in your malloc'd area happen to start with a 0, then that's a valid 0-length string and you got lucky. If they contain no zeros, then strcat will shit over random memory and corrupt something or crash.

Comment: @Chris, by passing the pointer you could have modified the original string buffer (str_input) that you passed to the function however, once you did str = realloc(...) you overwrote that pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Slowly getting the hang of this, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You are missing that C **always use pass by value**.

That means that you can't change `str` in main inside the function because `str` in the function is just a copy of `str` in main. No matter how many change you make to that copy, `str` in main is unchanged.

Since you want to change `str` in main the function must be:

```
void get_input(char **str)
```

and be called like:

```
get_input(&str_input);
```

As an alternative you can let `get_input` return a pointer like:

```
char* get_input(char *str)
{
     …
     return newPointer;
}
```

and call it like:

```
 str_input = get_input(str_input);
```

Comment: Also, the memory isn't initialized before passing it to strcat().

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker true.... there are multiple errors here but I think the main problem is that OP expects to be able to update `str` in main

Comment: @4386427 I thought I was accounting for that by using a pointer. If the address the pointer refers to gets copied to a new pointer, they're still pointing to the same location in memory, and therefore the change should persist beyond the function's lifetime, shouldn't it? I guess I should read up some more on pointers... Anyway your solution works, thanks!

Comment: @4386427 and @Chris if he just modified the content of `str` in the called function, it would have reflected in the `Main()`. But he does reallocation to pointer str and so it points to different location.